# Eye Tracking , Gaze Tracking method needed

Tags: c++, opencv, eye-detection

I am working on a project to detect Eye Gaze using opencv in the C++ language ,
I was able to detect the face and the eyes , but still no luck with making it stable

The main problem is that when I ask to detect the right eye for example sometimes it gets mixed up with the left eye , even though I am using the cascade that is for the right eye

So , the question is how to restrict the detection on specific eye with no collision with the other , and if you have any good way to use the detected parts in the gaze estimation , I can provide the code if it is needed

Best to you all ,
Ahmad

Comment: Hello Ahmad, what about detecting both eyes and then saying left one is left eye and right one is right eye? It will not confuse.

Comment: what I meant is when detecting the eyes and showing the detected eye it keeps flipping right and left , so for example you are showing the left eye it gives you the left eye then after some frames it will show the right eye and so on

Comment: So you mean due to some imperfection, left and right eye are switching? If so, I will suggest to not use cascade for for eyes at all. Instead, use cascade to detect (face and) eyes and take control yourself to decide which is which eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm a new user so I cannot comment.

Do you have access to the entire face? If so you can use simple geometry to set the region of interest to exclude the right part of the face, and run the eye cascade only on the left side, for example.

It's also useful to exclude the bottom (mouth) since the eye cascade gives a lot of false positives.

Comment: I will try to use resize for the window 2 times one for the left and one for the right and run cascade on both resized windows and see how it goes , thanks for the idea , I was hoping for less work solution

Comment: if it works for you do you mind marking it as an answer? new user needs karma. :)

Comment: Ha ha.. @CelsoCardoso.. I am upvoting.. for Karma; now 1 to 11 :D